# Part of longer code has an error - how can I debug?

Tags: manipulate

Please can someone help me locate the problem?

```
Manipulate [ Module [ {g, c, \[Theta]},
o1 = {0, 0};
o2 = {g, 0};
crankPosition = c* {Cos[\[Theta]], Sin[\[Theta]]};
groundLink = Line [ { o1, o2}];
crank = Line [ {o1, crankPosition}];
Show [ Graphics[{ groundLink , crank}]]], {\[Theta], 0, 
2 \[Pi]}, {g, 0, 5} , {c, 0, 9}]
```

Comment: Try getting rid of `Module`.  `Manipulate` already (correctly) uses `DynamicModule` internally.

Comment: Coordinate {$CellContext`c$309397 Cos[$CellContext`\[Theta]$309397], $CellContext`c$309397 Sin[$CellContext`\[Theta]$309397]} should be a pair of numbers, or a Scaled or Offset form.  ........

Comment: Did you remove `Module` as I instructed?  That error does not remain if I do.

Comment: Yes . Thanx .why no output if variables crankPosition , groundLink defined as functions ?? functions of g,c & Theta ?

Comment: You should include code for a minimum working example.  Don't make us guess what you are writing.

Answer (score 1):

Just following up [Mr.Wizard's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/121/mr-wizard) comment (remove `Module`), you can localize the other variables with `With` or however one wishes, or let them be global.

```
Manipulate[
 With[{
   o1 = {0, 0},
   o2 = {g, 0},
   crankPosition = c*{Cos[θ], Sin[θ]}},
  With[{
    groundLink = Line[{o1, o2}],
    crank = Line[{o1, crankPosition}]},
   Show[Graphics[{groundLink, crank}]]
   ]],
 {θ, 0, 2 π}, {g, 0, 5}, {c, 0, 9}]
```

(The OP's `Module` creates new variables with the same names as the `Manipulate` variables.  The `Module` variables shadow the `Manipulate` variables, which means they block the values of the `Manipulate` variables from being used inside the `Module`.)